# SQL how to count all rows up to a max value

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1111

I am having trouble counting the number of rows until it reaches a certain PK.

My PK is called id and I want to count all rows until i reach a specified id

I have tried using this query but it doesn't work probably becuase I am using a MySQL table

```
select max(count(*)) from news where id=18 group by id
```

I get this error

> Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following:

```
select count(id) from news where id <= 18
```

This will be more efficient as you are only returning one column in a row as opposed to all of them.

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(*) from news where id<=18
```